# How does multiprocessing module provide remote concurrency?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I understand that in ***concurrent.futures*** module, ***ProcessPoolExecutor*** subclass uses ***multiprocessing*** module to spawn multiple processes.

Is it possible to achieve this concurrency on a remote machine? If yes, how is the memory shared or allocated by different processes?

***What are the other challenges of achieving this multiprocessing on a remote machine?***

I have tried local concurrency using this method. I just want to know if remote concurrency can help me achieve even better performance.

Comment: Are you talking about cloud computing? What do you mean?

Comment: I just want to know how remote concurrency can be achieved using multiprocessing module. Whether or not we can use cores on any other machine than your local machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple machines at your disposal, then definitely you could achieve better performance by using them. It will make sense only for bigger workloads, because of the latency of the remote machine and communication overhead.

In the industry tools like (Py)Spark and (Py)Mesos are more popular for this task.

You can use `multiprocessing`, here is an example from [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html):

> Running the following commands creates a server for a single shared
>   queue which remote clients can access:

```
>>> from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
>>> from queue import Queue
>>> queue = Queue()
>>> class QueueManager(BaseManager): pass
>>> QueueManager.register('get_queue', callable=lambda:queue)
>>> m = QueueManager(address=('', 50000), authkey=b'abracadabra')
>>> s = m.get_server()
>>> s.serve_forever()
```

> One client can access the server as follows:

```
>>> from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
>>> class QueueManager(BaseManager): pass
>>> QueueManager.register('get_queue')
>>> m = QueueManager(address=('foo.bar.org', 50000), authkey=b'abracadabra')
>>> m.connect()
>>> queue = m.get_queue()
>>> queue.put('hello')
```

> Another client can also use it:

```
>>> from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
>>> class QueueManager(BaseManager): pass
>>> QueueManager.register('get_queue')
>>> m = QueueManager(address=('foo.bar.org', 50000), authkey=b'abracadabra')
>>> m.connect()
>>> queue = m.get_queue()
>>> queue.get()
'hello'
```